# After uploading app signing sha-1 in google developer console my authentication is not working

Tags: java

My Google Authentication is not working. I tried to upload play store App Signing Certificate SHA-1 key to my Google Developer Console and it was working for some time but after few days it stops working.
I checked my key again and it is same as before.
And also i got Google error 10 again

Answer (score 0):

Found it..!!
I forgot to add Web Client's Id in     GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(webClientId)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
And now it is working..

But new problem is created now.. 
This application work only in debug mode, not in signed Apk mode.. 
I don't know why.. :|